# running cmd commands through java

Tags: java, process, cmd, exec

i am trying to save the logcat of an Android device by executing cmd commands through java,although the file i specify in which the logcat to be saved to is never created.Can anybody tell me why this happens?
the cmd command i want to perform is "adb logcat > C:/Users/user1/Desktop/log1.txt".
and the code I use to execute it is:

```
try {
    // create a new array of 4 strings
    String[] cmdArray = new String[4];

    cmdArray[0] = "adb";
    cmdArray[1] = " logcat";
    cmdArray[2] = " >";
    cmdArray[3] = " C:/Users/amantsakov/Desktop/logcat.txt";

    // create a process and execute cmdArray
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did this work in normal command prompt? In windows `\\` backslash is the path separator.

Comment: @Codebender, the forward slash work in Java in Windows... As does \\

Comment: @Danielson what exactly is your question?

Comment: You said `the cmd command i want to perform is "adb logcat > C:/Users/user1/Desktop/log1.txt".`, But you are running `Android` (according to the tags). But Android has no `Desktop` not `C:`, so I'm confused

Comment: oh no sorry i am not running android the device from which i get the logs is android.
i am new to all this so should i remove the tag to avoid further confusion?

Comment: Yes, if it is not relevant for the question, don't add...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work for you

```
String[] exeCmd = new String[] { "ffmpeg", "-i", "C:\\test\\Veham.mp3",
                "-i", "C:\\test\\test.mp4", "-acodec", "copy", "-vcodec",
                "copy", "C:\\test\\outPut.mp4" };

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(exeCmd);
        boolean exeCmdStatus = executeCMD(pb);

        return exeCmdStatus;


private static boolean executeCMD(ProcessBuilder pb) {
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = null;

        try {
            p = pb.start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("oops");
            p.destroy();
            return false;
        }
        // wait until the process is done
        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("woopsy");
            p.destroy();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }// End function executeCMD
```

these method will help to run cmd command from java.